How can I update certificates on winrm when there are two HTTPS listeners?
I have two HTTPS listeners (One Compatibility) on winrm as follows:
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname = <hostname here>
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = <thumb here>
    ListeningOn = <not important>

Listener [Source="Compatibility"]
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 443
    Hostname = <hostname here>
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = <thumb here>
    ListeningOn = <same as above not important>

I can update the certificate just fine for the 5986 Listener, but when I try to update the 443 listener there seems to be no way to specify the port. Since the address and the transport are the same, I'm unsure how else I can get the Listener I want.
I've tried some of the following:
Invalid use of command line error:
winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS+Port=443 @{CertificateThumbprint="<Thumbprint>"}

These don't work, but I didn't delete the old one before running create as I want to update in place:
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="<hostname>"; CertificateThumbprint="<Thumbprint>"; Port=443}'  

winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="<hostname>"; CertificateThumbprint="<Thumbprint>"; Port="443"}'

No Error using the listener name, but didn't update the cert when running Get-Item to confirm
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Listener\Listener_874393735\CertificateThumbprint -Value <Thumbprint>

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Listener\Listener_874393735\CertificateThumbprint -Value "<Thumbprint>" 

Error Message: This resource requires the following selectors: Address Transport
Set-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config/Listener -SelectorSet @{Address="*"; Transport="HTTPS";Port="443"} -ValueSet @{CertificateThumbprint=$certThumb}

So after all that my question is two fold.

Is having two HTTPS listeners even a valid configuration that is supported?
If so, how do I go about updating the Compatibility cert?


The only solution I found for this was to reset the configuration, as trying to delete the default listener would cause commands to fail to try to update or create any new listeners.
Here are the steps I took:

winrm invoke Restore winrm/Config
Make sure the new certificate is in the certificate store and old certificates are gone
`winrm quickconfig -transport:https (creates the 5986 listener using new cert)
Run winrm get winrm/config/service to find the correct attribute to enable the compatibility https listener because mine had different casing than documentation I found on line.
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener="true"}' (creates the 443 listener using new cert)

Obviously not an ideal solution because it requires resetting the entire config instead of just updating the cert, but it worked for me.

Perhaps I may have also been able to do this by setting EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener="false" and then setting it to true again.
